# latex error: environment proof undefined

Tags: latex, texmaker

hi i am using latex... wanted to use the following:

```
       \begin{proof}
       ...
       \end{proof}
```

it gives me the following error:
!Latex error: Environment proof undefined. can you help me to solve this problem? thanks

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The `proof` environment is part of AMS-LaΤεχ, not plain LaΤεχ, so you need to:

```
\usepackage{amsthm}
```

See this [AMS-LaTeX page](http://www.stat.umn.edu/~charlie/amslatex.html) for details. If you don't already have the packages installed, grab them at http://www.ams.org/tex/amslatex.html

Answer (score 4):

[The `proof` environment requires the `amsthm` package](ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/doc/amscls/amsthdoc.pdf).

`amsthm` is contained in `amsmath` which you can get from [the AMS-LaTeX package here](http://www.ams.org/tex/amslatex.html).